# Unclear result with running a separate thread

Tags: multithreading, scala, java-threads

I have something which I thought would be straightforward, but then I encounter a problem which I don't understand after thinking a while.

So here is a simple minimal piece of code involving two threads:

```
package com.alexander.arendar

package object concscalaprog {

  def thread(block: =>Unit):Thread = {
    val t = new Thread{
      override def run(): Unit = block
    }
    t.run()
    t
  }
}
```

and

```
package com.alexander.arendar.concscalaprog

object Chapter2 {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val t1 = thread(println(Thread.currentThread().getName))
    t1.join()
  }

}
```

I expected to see in the console something different from

> main

but this was exactly what I saw as the program output.
Could you guys help me understand why doesn't it print out the name of the separate thread it creates?

Comment: Here is how I'd paraphrase it in one line: `lazy val t: Thread = new Thread { override def run(): Unit = { println(Thread.currentThread == t) } }; t.run`. Now, "why does this print `false`?".

Comment: I was reading the book and trying to do exercises in the end of a chapter and noticed that my solution does not behave under tests as I expected. So I minified the example and not able to see the reason.
Your example is even more difficult for me to understand, so I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet

```
val t = new Thread{
  override def run(): Unit = block
}
t.run()
```

defines variable `t` of type `Thread` with an overridden method `run`, and then *immediately invokes `run` on the same thread*.

It's no different than writing

```
abstract class Q { def bar(): Unit }
val q = new Q { def bar(): Unit = println(Thread.currentThread.getName) }
q.bar()
```

The fact that `t` is of type `Thread` while `q` is of type `Q` is irrelevant: both `run` and `bar` are executed on the main thread, using the same stack.

Just replace `run()` by `start()`.

Here is a shorter example that demonstrates it:

```
lazy val t: Thread = new Thread { 
  override def run(): Unit = { println(Thread.currentThread == t) } 
}
t.run()
```

gives `false`, whereas

```
lazy val t: Thread = new Thread { 
  override def run(): Unit = { println(Thread.currentThread == t) } 
}
t.start()
```

gives `true`.

Comment: shame on me. I see now.

Comment: When I commented on your question, I didn't know the answer either, had to re-read p.32 to bump into the `t.start()` line ;) Admittedly, kind-of obvious once you see it, but somewhat surprising if the `run/start` distinction isn't fresh in working memory.